# ADFS2.0 SP-Initiated URL?

Tags: saml, adfs

We've deployed an ADFS Server and its associated proxy, with our application as the relying party, and a cloud identity provider (Covisint) as Claims Provider.

We have tested the ADFS server using Active directory as the claims provider, and the authentication process is successful end to end.

When we switch the application's home realm over to use the cloud provider, the process seems to work, up to the point where the cloud provider returns the now-logged-in user back to https://[adfs url]/adfs/ls

This is what we had supplied the cloud identity provider with for the SP-initatied URL for them to return logged in users to, but it appears to be incorrect, or incorrectly configured, as it presents the user with the below error.

What is the URL that the cloud provider should post logged in users to for SAML2.0 on ADFS2.0?

I should also note, even logged in users are being redirected to the cloud provider on access to the app, leading me to believe that a necessary SAML>ADFS post has not happened yet.

Error:

`There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference number to identify the problem.
Reference number: 4973cca5-db6f-43dd-bd9b-59fa9872e97c`

There is nothing in the trace or admin logs of use.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the path RP --> ADFS --> (SAML) --> Cloud Provider? So when you navigate to the application, you get the Home Realm Discovery screen, you then pick the Cloud Povider and then authenticate? I assume your RP is ASP.NET with WIF? You sent the cloud provider the ADFS metadata? Just to confirm that you looked in the AD FS 2.0 and AD FS 2.0 Tracing sections of the Event Log?

Comment: Yes on all counts. Neither of the logs have nothing of interest, as it appears that the whole transaction is somehow losing its context on the way back in from the cloud provider, and becoming a direct hit against http://[adfs]/adfs/ls instead of completing the saml transaction